# Regression and Cross-Validation of Regression - why different p-values?

Tags: regression, cross-validation

I have an R question. I'm wondering why there is a difference in p-values in the original regression analysis using lm versus in the k-fold cross-validation using the DAAG package.

So, first I run the regression.

```
Model = lm(ExampleData$DependentVariable ~ ExampleData$IV1  + ExampleData$IV2  + ExampleData$IV3  + ExampleData$IV4)
```

This gives me the p-values for the predictors (shown below).

```
(Intercept)  = 0.01958 *, ExampleData$IV1  =  0.05631 ., ExampleData$IV2  =  0.00295 **, ExampleData$IV3  =  0.00492 **, ExampleData$IV4  = 0.00473 **
```

Then, I go to cross-validate the model using cv.lm in the DAAG package.

```
cv.lm(df=ExampleData, Model_forCV, m=5)
```

This gives me the cross-validation results along with the p-values for the predictors (shown below).

```
IV1  = 0.07541 . , IV2  = 0.00059 ***, IV3  = 0.03938 * , IV4  = 0.00473 **
```

Why are the p-values different?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is an intercept term missing in the second model. Or is that hidden.

A missing intercept term would explain the changing p-values. it would change the std error, the t-value and hence the p-value. Not to mention change the regression coefficients as well (as you can see in your results).